# How do I pass arguments to Laravel commands scheduled from the Kernel?

Tags: php, laravel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-10

In Laravel 10, I am trying to schedule multiple commands in the Kernel class. They use the same Command class/signature but send different arguments. I think I have followed [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands) correctly and I have tried both formats.

Kernel:

```
$schedule->command('import:markers Texas')->everyMinute(); 
OR
$schedule->command(ImportMarkers::class, ['Texas'])->everyMinute();
```

This works as expected:

```
php artisan import:markers Texas
```

But using the scheduler, I get a FAIL message for both styles of command:

```
php artisan schedule:run
2023-10-25 21:08:51 Running ['artisan' import:markers Texas] ......... 1,999ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.4/bin/php' 'artisan' import:markers Texas > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can define your scheduled command in the Kernel.

```
$schedule->command('import:markers')
    ->appendOutputTo('import_markers.log') // Optional: Log the output to a file
    ->parameters(['Texas'])
    ->everyMinute();
```

Comment: Thank you. That format has the same result.

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel logs?